# Responsive Multi-Level Menu - How to close menu when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have a very simple menu, no sub menus and was curious how I would get the menu to close when I click on one of the links?

[Plugin Home Page ->](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/)

Here is the code directly out of the .js file that comes in the zip when you download this menu. I really need to know what code to add and where to add it so that when I click a link it closes the menu.

```
            ;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

            'use strict';

            // global
            var Modernizr = window.Modernizr, $body = $( 'body' );

            $.DLMenu = function( options, element ) {
                this.$el = $( element );
                this._init( options );
            };

            // the options
            $.DLMenu.defaults = {
                // classes for the animation effects
                animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-1', classout : 'dl-animate-out-1' },
                // callback: click a link that has a sub menu
                // el is the link element (li); name is the level name
                onLevelClick : function( el, name ) { return false; },
                // callback: click a link that does not have a sub menu
                // el is the link element (li); ev is the event obj
                onLinkClick : function( el, ev ) { return false; }
            };

            $.DLMenu.prototype = {
                _init : function( options ) {

                    // options
                    this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DLMenu.defaults, options );
                    // cache some elements and initialize some variables
                    this._config();

                    var animEndEventNames = {
                            'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                            'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
                            'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
                            'animation' : 'animationend'
                        },
                        transEndEventNames = {
                            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                            'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                            'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                            'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                            'transition' : 'transitionend'
                        };
                    // animation end event name
                    this.animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ] + '.dlmenu';
                    // transition end event name
                    this.transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ] + '.dlmenu',
                    // support for css animations and css transitions
                    this.supportAnimations = Modernizr.cssanimations,
                    this.supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

                    this._initEvents();

                },
                _config : function() {
                    this.open = false;
                    this.$trigger = this.$el.children( '.dl-trigger' );
                    this.$menu = this.$el.children( 'ul.dl-menu' );
                    this.$menuitems = this.$menu.find( 'li:not(.dl-back)' );
                    this.$el.find( 'ul.dl-submenu' ).prepend( '<li class="dl-back"><a href="#">BACK</a></li>' );
                    this.$back = this.$menu.find( 'li.dl-back' );
                },
                _initEvents : function() {

                    var self = this;

                    this.$trigger.on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {

                        if( self.open ) {
                            self._closeMenu();
                        } 
                        else {
                            self._openMenu();
                        }
                        return false;

                    } );

                    this.$menuitems.on( 'click.dlmenu', function( event ) {

                        event.stopPropagation();

                        var $item = $(this),
                            $submenu = $item.children( 'ul.dl-submenu' );

                        if( $submenu.length > 0 ) {

                            var $flyin = $submenu.clone().css( 'opacity', 0 ).insertAfter( self.$menu ),
                                onAnimationEndFn = function() {
                                    self.$menu.off( self.animEndEventName ).removeClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout ).addClass( 'dl-subview' );
                                    $item.addClass( 'dl-subviewopen' ).parents( '.dl-subviewopen:first' ).removeClass( 'dl-subviewopen' ).addClass( 'dl-subview' );
                                    $flyin.remove();
                                };

                            setTimeout( function() {
                                $flyin.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
                                self.$menu.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout );
                                if( self.supportAnimations ) {
                                    self.$menu.on( self.animEndEventName, onAnimationEndFn );
                                }
                                else {
                                    onAnimationEndFn.call();
                                }

                                self.options.onLevelClick( $item, $item.children( 'a:first' ).text() );
                            } );

                            return false;

                        }
                        var link = $item.find('a').attr('href');
                        var hash = link.substring(link.indexOf('#')+1);
                        if( hash != "" ){
                        var elem = jQuery('div[data-anchor="'+hash+'"]');
                        autoScroll(elem);
                        self._closeMenu();
                        }else{
                        self.options.onLinkClick( $item, event );
                        }

                    } );

                    this.$back.on( 'click.dlmenu', function( event ) {

                        var $this = $( this ),
                            $submenu = $this.parents( 'ul.dl-submenu:first' ),
                            $item = $submenu.parent(),

                            $flyin = $submenu.clone().insertAfter( self.$menu );

                        var onAnimationEndFn = function() {
                            self.$menu.off( self.animEndEventName ).removeClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
                            $flyin.remove();
                        };

                        setTimeout( function() {
                            $flyin.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout );
                            self.$menu.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
                            if( self.supportAnimations ) {
                                self.$menu.on( self.animEndEventName, onAnimationEndFn );
                            }
                            else {
                                onAnimationEndFn.call();
                            }

                            $item.removeClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );

                            var $subview = $this.parents( '.dl-subview:first' );
                            if( $subview.is( 'li' ) ) {
                                $subview.addClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );
                            }
                            $subview.removeClass( 'dl-subview' );
                        } );

                        return false;

                    } );

                },
                closeMenu : function() {
                    if( this.open ) {
                        this._closeMenu();
                    }
                },
                _closeMenu : function() {
                    var self = this,
                        onTransitionEndFn = function() {
                            self.$menu.off( self.transEndEventName );
                            self._resetMenu();
                        };

                    this.$menu.removeClass( 'dl-menuopen' );
                    this.$menu.addClass( 'dl-menu-toggle' );
                    this.$trigger.removeClass( 'dl-active' );

                    if( this.supportTransitions ) {
                        this.$menu.on( this.transEndEventName, onTransitionEndFn );
                    }
                    else {
                        onTransitionEndFn.call();
                    }

                    this.open = false;
                },
                openMenu : function() {
                    if( !this.open ) {
                        this._openMenu();
                    }
                },
                _openMenu : function() {
                    var self = this;
                    // clicking somewhere else makes the menu close
                    $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {
                        self._closeMenu() ;
                    } );
                    this.$menu.addClass( 'dl-menuopen dl-menu-toggle' ).on( this.transEndEventName, function() {
                        $( this ).removeClass( 'dl-menu-toggle' );
                    } );
                    this.$trigger.addClass( 'dl-active' );
                    this.open = true;
                },
                // resets the menu to its original state (first level of options)
                _resetMenu : function() {
                    this.$menu.removeClass( 'dl-subview' );
                    this.$menuitems.removeClass( 'dl-subview dl-subviewopen' );
                }
            };

            var logError = function( message ) {
                if ( window.console ) {
                    window.console.error( message );
                }
            };

            $.fn.dlmenu = function( options ) {
                if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
                    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
                    this.each(function() {
                        var instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu' );
                        if ( !instance ) {
                            logError( "cannot call methods on dlmenu prior to initialization; " +
                            "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                            return;
                        }
                        if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                            logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for dlmenu instance" );
                            return;
                        }
                        instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
                    });
                } 
                else {
                    this.each(function() {  
                        var instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu' );
                        if ( instance ) {
                            instance._init();
                        }
                        else {
                            instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu', new $.DLMenu( options, this ) );
                        }
                    });
                }
                return this;
            };

        } )( jQuery, window );
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to add more detail. Include the markup for your menu and the javascript that you have tried.

Comment: I will remember to do that the next time I post something like this, sorry. But the answer given has solved the issue. Thanks !

Comment: I tried, but Stack said I need 15 rep to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at their demo, it seems you can call method plugins. Replace dl-menu with the id of your menu.

```
$('#dl-menu a').click(function(e) {
      $('#dl-menu').dlmenu('closeMenu'); 
});
```